# Teamcity. Run powershell script after the build to install windows service

Tags: .net, teamcity, teamcity-7.1

I have two build configurations:

- Build solution and run tests
- Deploy ASP.NET site using msbuild

That article http://www.troyhunt.com/2010/11/you-deploying-it-wrong-teamcity.html was used as manual.

Currently I want to add the third build configuration to install a windows service. There is a powershell script that should be run from bin folder (release, debug etc).

So the question is how access the build folder (something like C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\94fc00f485df5f29\Solution\Service\bin\%environment%) to run that script? As I understand the guid from url is not static and I couldn't hardcode it in teamcity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set the path to your build script, just set it so its like:

```
Solution\Service\bin\%environment%
```

Which will do it relatively to the build directory for your build agent.

Otherwise I think its:

```
%teamcity.build.checkoutDir%\Solution\Service\bin\%environment%
```

Which TeamCity will fill in `%teamcity.build.checkoutDir%` with like `C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\94fc00f485df5f29`